# Sorting chacters in String using QuickSort

Tags: c#, quicksort

Good day we are given an assignment to get a user string input and then sort the characters inside
input is: fedbac
output must be: abcdef

i have tried quicksort in an integer but having a hard time translating it into a char. heres my code below. Can you help me point out what should be changed and why?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace Intern_Skill_Test
{
    class MethodQuickSort
    {
        public void QuickSort(string input)
        {
            string inputLower = input.ToLower();
            char[] charArr = inputLower.ToCharArray();

            quickSortMerge(charArr,'0' ,charArr.Length -1);
            for(int i = 0; i < charArr.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.Write(charArr[i]);
            }
        }

        public static void quickSortMerge(char[] charArr, int start, int end)
        {
            if(start < end)
            {
                int pivot = partition(charArr, start, end);
                quickSortMerge(charArr, start, pivot -1);
                quickSortMerge(charArr, pivot + 1, end);
            }
        }
        public static char partition(char[] charArr, int start, int end)
        {
            int pivot = charArr[end];
            char pIndex = start;
            for(int i = start; i < end; i++)
            {
                if(charArr[i] <= pivot)
                {
                    char temp = charArr[i];
                    charArr[i] = charArr[pIndex];
                    charArr[pIndex] = temp;
                    pIndex++;
                }
            }

            char anotherTemp = charArr[pIndex];
            charArr[pIndex] = charArr[end];
            charArr[end] = anotherTemp;
            return pIndex;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: What about `Array.Sort`?

Comment: What about surrogate pairs consisting of two char?

Answer (score 0):

The 2nd parameter to `quickSortMerge()` is an index and should be zero `0`, not a character `'0'`...

```
quickSortMerge(charArr, /*'0'*/ 0 ,charArr.Length -1); //
```

You want `partition` to return an `int` and for `pIndex` to be an `int` too.

```
public static /*char*/ int partition(...
{
    int pivot = charArr[end];
    /*char*/ int pIndex = start;
```

You might also consider making the class static.